# Buscar menores valores de um campo conforme valores de outro

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-select, group-by

Tenho estes dados inseridos em minha tabela.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM db_cotacao;

+----+------------+-------+------------+--------+---------+
| id | data       | valor | validade   | idforn | idativo |
+----+------------+-------+------------+--------+---------+
|  1 | 2019-02-10 |    20 | 2020-07-02 |      1 |       1 |
|  2 | 2019-02-10 |    30 | 2020-07-02 |      1 |       2 |
|  3 | 2019-02-10 |    40 | 2020-07-02 |      1 |       3 |
|  4 | 2019-02-10 |     5 | 2020-07-02 |      2 |       1 |
|  5 | 2019-02-10 |     8 | 2020-07-02 |      2 |       2 |
|  6 | 2019-02-10 |     4 | 2020-07-02 |      2 |       3 |
+----+------------+-------+------------+--------+---------+
```

Eu gostaria de fazer uma busca onde me apresentasse um grupo do campo *idativo* com os menores valores do campo *valor*.

Uso a seguinte *query*:

```
mysql> SELECT idforn, idativo, MIN(valor) AS minimo FROM db_cotacao
    -> GROUP BY idativo;

+--------+---------+--------+
| idforn | idativo | minimo |
+--------+---------+--------+
|      1 |       1 |      5 |
|      1 |       2 |      8 |
|      1 |       3 |      4 |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

Apresenta os menores valores corretamente. Porém o campo *idforn* não corresponde aos menores valores e sim aos primeiros itens agrupados.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo. É a primeira vez que uso o site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar variáveis internas para organizar os dados da forma que deseja:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @idativo    = 0;
SET @minimo     = 0;

SELECT x.idforn,
       x.idativo,
       x.minimo
  FROM (
  SELECT @row_number := CASE
                          WHEN @idativo = idativo THEN @row_number + 1
                          ELSE 1
                        END AS sequencia,
         @menor := CASE
                     WHEN @idativo <> idativo OR @minimo > dc.valor THEN dc.valor
                     ELSE @minimo
                   END AS minimo,
         @idativo := idativo,
         dc.*
    FROM db_cotacao dc
   ORDER BY idativo,
            idforn DESC
  ) x
 WHERE x.sequencia = 1
 ORDER BY x.idativo
```

Resultando em:

```
| idforn | idativo | minimo |
| ------ | ------- | ------ |
| 2      | 1       | 5      |
| 2      | 2       | 8      |
| 2      | 3       | 4      |
```

Confira o resultado no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dqsz4CNzVBi2jG7TbeZGnt/0).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 1):

O agrupamento, unifica em um linha os registros com o mesmo valor(es) definido(s) na declaração GROUP BY. Quando o MySQL faz isso, ele mantem o primeiro registro. Imagine que ele segure o primeiro registro daquele valor(es) e vai descartando os demais, e apenas mantem o valor da declaração MIN, até fechar um grupo e assim por diante. Em uma versão do MariaDB (não sei especificamente qual), ocorre isto também, entretanto ele mantem o último registro ao invés do primeiro.

Para resolver isso, basta criar uma tabela temporária, ordenando (ASC ou DESC dependendo de qual ele mantem) a coluna a ser utilizado o MIN e a coluna a ser agrupada. Depois, em um *select*, utilize o agrupamento com o comando MIN.

Veja este [*fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf096d/3).

```
create table db_cotacao (
  id int primary key, data date, valor decimal(4,2), validade date, idforn int, idativo int,
  index(idativo),
  index(idforn)
);

insert into db_cotacao values
(1, '2019-02-10', 20, '2020-07-02', 1, 1),
(2, '2019-02-10', 30, '2020-07-02', 1, 2),
(3, '2019-02-10', 40, '2020-07-02', 1, 3),
(4, '2019-02-10',  5, '2020-07-02', 2, 1),
(5, '2019-02-10',  8, '2020-07-02', 2, 2),                                    
(6, '2019-02-10',  4, '2020-07-02', 2, 3);

#Usei tabela não temporária devida à restrição do *fiddle*.
CREATE table tbOrdened
SELECT id, idforn, idativo, valor FROM db_cotacao order by valor asc, idativo;

SELECT idforn, idativo, min(valor) AS valor from tbOrdened as tb1 GROUP BY idativo;
```

Qualquer dúvida, deixe um comentário.

Comment: O MySQL diz que o group não tem garantia de qual vai ser retornado.